# What does "registered pursuant" mean in German laws?

Tags: legal-terms, germany

I find the phrase **registered pursuant** used a lot in the German law of registration. Could someone explain what it means?

Reference from [Federal Ministry of Justice](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Which law is that?

The link goes to the [Bundesmeldegesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/). That law regulates the duties and rights of citizens to register with the Meldebehörden, especially their **place of residence** (§17).

### registered pursuant?

The combination "registered pursuant" only appears **twice** in exactly that order in the whole law: §27 and §29. They read as below:

> §27 (2) Anyone who is registered in Germany pursuant to Section 17 or 28 and moves to a residence for a stay of no more than six months shall not be required to register or deregister at this residence. For persons who otherwise live abroad and are not registered pursuant to Section 17 (1), this obligation shall apply after three months have elapsed.

> §29 (4) Persons spending the night in tents, caravans, motor caravans or water vessels at commercially operated sites shall not be subject to the requirement to register pursuant to Section 17 (1) and (2) as long as they are registered in Germany pursuant to Section 17 or 28. Anyone who is not registered pursuant to Section 17 or 28 shall register with the registration authority within two weeks as soon as his or her stay exceeds three months. Subsections 2 and 3 shall apply accordingly.

At other times, the two are ripped apart, but for the exemplary character, let's just look at those two. Looking to the german side, and with knowledge of German, someone would realize that in this case, the two words are not connected as a standing term but are used in a phrase that mimics the structure *[someone] registered pursuant to Section 17[...]*.

The combination is the translation of "*[Personen, die] nach § 17 Absatz 1 gemeldet sind,*" and its variations, and that can also be translated "registered (*gemeldet*) according to (=pursuant, *nach* but also *gemäß*) § 17"

Answer (score 6):

The linked text is the official translation of the [Bundesmeldegesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/index.html) (BMG) of 3 May 2013, as amended up to 2017.

As an example, since the words are used in many places, let's look at Section 27(2). This says:

> Anyone who is registered in Germany pursuant to Section 17 or 28 and moves to a residence for a stay of no more than six months shall not be required to register or deregister at this residence. Anyone who has not moved out of this residence after six months have elapsed shall register with the registration authority within two weeks. For persons who otherwise live abroad and are not registered pursuant to Section 17 (1), this obligation shall apply after three months have elapsed.

Being registered "pursuant to" those sections means that the person has been registered in the manner described in that part of the text. These words are translating German *nach*, e.g. "Wer im Inland nach § 17 oder § 28 gemeldet ist", with the same sense of "according to" or "following" the cited provision of law.

Section 17 is the usual registration process, and Section 28 is a special one for "sailors on inland waterways and the high seas". So "anyone who is registered in Germany pursuant to Section 17" means anyone who has completed the formal steps of registering at their residence as required in that section. Likewise, someone registered "pursuant to Section 28" is a crew member of certain vessels where a different process applies, and has registered in that way.

The word "pursuant" appears many other times, such as in 27(1),

> national volunteer service pursuant to the Federal Volunteer Service Act
>
> Bundesfreiwilligendienst nach dem Bundesfreiwilligendienstgesetz

Again, this is a reference to the cited provision of law, to clarify precisely what is meant by the term "Bundesfreiwilligendienst".

Comment: not just *nach* but also *gemäß*